# Cannot build with different build.gradle file

Tags: android, gradle

I run this command

```
gradle -b android-lite/build.gradle assembleDebug
```

build command works, but If I running command with different build file `build-with-jars.gradle`

```
gradle -b android-lite/build-with-jars.gradle assembleDebug
```

I get error

> Build file '/Users/username/git/android-project/android-lite/build-with-jars.gradle' is not part of the build defined by settings file '/Users/username/git/android/settings.gradle'. If this is an unrelated build, it must have its own settings file.

What does it mean? I have to have a different settings file for each build.gradle?